# Reload data is not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been banging my head against the wall since I thought I tried everything possible on stackoverflow.

So currently I am creating a table like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSLog(@"CHECK IF THIS IS CALLED");
  static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"CellIdentifier";
  CBPeripheral *placeHolder;

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
  // Using a cell identifier will allow your app to reuse cells as they come and go from the screen.
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
  }
       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
       placeHolder = _connectedPeripherals[indexPath.row];
       cell.textLabel.text = placeHolder.name;
   }
   return cell;
}
```

and I am calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` from another function that I call. I know it's getting called in that function, but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` does not get called again.

I created a `UITableView` property on my .h file
`@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;`

And created the table like this

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
self.tableView.rowHeight = 60.0f;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;



self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addConstraints:@[ [HTConstraints leftAlignView:self.tableView
                                                 toView:self.view
                                            withSpacing:5],

                           [HTConstraints topAlignView:self.tableView
                                                toView:self.view
                                           withSpacing:5],

                           [HTConstraints rightAlignView:self.tableView
                                                  toView:self.view
                                             withSpacing:5],

                           [HTConstraints bottomAlignView:self.tableView
                                                   toView:self.view
                                              withSpacing:5],
                           ]];
```

So far what I've tried was making sure that `[self.tableView reloadData]` was being called in the Main thread. Making sure my sections did not return 0.

**Edit**
This is my reloadData function and is called in another class
by `[[RootViewController sharedInstance] reloadData];` and the log prints when I call it.

```
- (void)reloadData {
  NSLog(@"Reloading");
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with the method that has the call to `reloadData`. Explain when and how that method is called.

Comment: how reloadData is called on main thread ?

Comment: @Mr.T I've checked for that. using `if [NSThread mainThread]` like I said in my post

Comment: did you implemented the numberOfRowsInSection method? Check if you are returning 0 in that method.

Comment: Did you also change/Update your data source (Arrays) before calling the `reloadTable` method? Do it as i said and it will be good to go & let me know what is the result.

Comment: Where are you allocating the tableView? You could be overwriting it. Make sure it's not nil when you call reloadData!

Comment: @AlexKoren In View didload

Comment: And you're positive you've done it after your [super viewDidLoad] call?

Comment: @AlexKoren just tripled checkeddd

Comment: Does your UIViewController conform to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols? (i.e. <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>)

Answer (score -1):

set a break point inside -(void)reloadData or try to append the count of your UITableView datasource in your NSLog.

Usually cellForRowAtIndexPath is not getting call because it does not have anything to display.

Answer (score -1):

I saw, in your code you forgot to add your `tableView` as a subView to the controller.
Add below code after your tableView's initialization

```
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Comment: Sorry, I saw you did it. Maybe check the frame of your `tableView`, if your `tableView`'s height equal to zero, it also causes the problem